# Android countdowntimer with game loop issue

Tags: android, multithreading, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer trying to count down from a surfaceview thread (not the main thread) which gives an exception "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". Looking at other answers they say to use a handler to solve the problem (I can't really use runonUIthread because I don't have access to any activity).

My question is how exactly do I use a handler in order to allow the below code to run as expected from a worker thread?

(For context I am trying to render some graphics onto the surfaceview canvas by changing their alpha at every tick of the countdown timer, hence doing it off the worker thread)

```
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            Log.e("TEST", ""+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             message = ("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() 
        {
            message = "finished";
            }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine handler and worker thread. create the handler in main thread, and use the handler reference in worker thread for UI update.

```
    public final static int MSG_TICK = 0;
    public final static int MSG_DONE = 1;
    public final static String KEY_MSG = "message";
```

deal with message and update UI

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()) {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_TICK:
                    Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        String content = bundle.getString(KEY_MSG);
                        // TODO: draw content
                    }
                    break;
                case MSG_DONE:
                    // TODO: draw content
                    break;
                }
            }

        };
```

send message from worker thread

```
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int seconds = 30;
                String message = null;
                while (seconds != 0) {
                    message = "seconds remaining: " + seconds;
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    // what message
                    msg.what = MSG_TICK;
                    // set data
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString(KEY_MSG, message);
                    msg.setData(data);

                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    --seconds;
                }

                message = "finished";
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DONE);
            }

        }).start();
```